# Auto-replace text with symbols in IntelliJ IDE?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellij-idea, plugins, autocomplete

VSCode has an awesome plugin [Symbol Complete](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sporiley.symbol-complete) that auto-replaces phrases with symbols based on regular expression rules. For example, if I type "lambda", it gets replaced by λ as soon as I type the last character "a". I'd like to have this same functionality in IntelliJ, but I can't seem to find a similar plugin. Does something like what I'm looking for exist?

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't directly answer the question, but I solved the problem (on Windows) by using [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) with its [HotStrings](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm).

Script:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

::lambda::λ
::pi::π
```

On MacOS, AHK isn't available, so I followed mwk's answer on this [AHK forum](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=27043) post:

> First, you may be able to accomplish all the key mapping you need via the
> stock system preferences on MacOS. Unlike, Windows, the Mac is very flexible > when it comes to managing keyboard shortcuts.
>
> Apple Menu -> System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts. You'll see a list > of the left side of the preference panel with a number of categories
> (Spotlight, etc.). The last item, "App Shortcuts", is where you can set your > own shortcuts for all applications or specific applications. It's amazing
> that Microsoft still doesn't offer this in Windows 10.

Comment: I don't think that response INDIRECTLY answers the question, either.  Especially for macOS. The feature mentioned here allows adding a shortcut key to activate an app's menu items, but it doesn't replace text the user has typed.